# Why is it a submanifold or not?

Tags: submanifold

I am looking at the following set $$M:=\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2:x^3 =y^3\}$$
I know the equivalent definition but I can't explain why this should be a submanifold or not. Can please someone gives me some basic explanation, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

The set is nothing but $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: y=x\}$.

---

Notes.

Also note that in order to talk about the notion of "[submanifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submanifold)", you should have *some* manifold in mind. Although, when the context is clear, people may not explicitly mention it.

Comment: I guess using the inverse function theorem would be a good idea but I don‘t know how

Comment: @FrederickManfred nothing fancy here. This the graph of the function $f(x)=x$.

Comment: Okay, so we will have that $M$ is a submanifold, becasue it can be represented locally as graph (in fact also globally not?)

Comment: What is your definition of submanifolds?

Comment: We have 4 equivalent definitions, but one says: “$M$ is locally the graph of a smooth function.

Comment: @FrederickManfred:  yes $M$ here is locally the graph of a smooth function. It is "globally" so in this example.

Comment: Hence it is a submanifold